# mlr_measures_classif.costs with predict_type = "prob"

Tags: r, mlr3

The cost-sensitive measure `mlr_measures_classif.costs` requires a `'response'` predict type.

```
msr("classif.costs")
#<MeasureClassifCosts:classif.costs>
#* Packages: -
#* Range: [-Inf, Inf]
#* Minimize: TRUE
#* Properties: requires_task
#* Predict type: response
```

This measure seems to be working even when a learner's `predict_type` is set to `'prob'`:

```
# get a cost sensitive task
task = tsk("german_credit")

# cost matrix as given on the UCI page of the german credit data set
# https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/statlog+(german+credit+data)
costs = matrix(c(0, 5, 1, 0), nrow = 2)
dimnames(costs) = list(truth = task$class_names, predicted = task$class_names)
print(costs)

# mlr3 needs truth in columns, predictions in rows
costs = t(costs)

# create measure which calculates the absolute costs
m = msr("classif.costs", id = "german_credit_costs", costs = costs, normalize = FALSE)

# fit models and calculate costs
learner = lrn("classif.rpart", predict_type = "prob")
rr = resample(task, learner, rsmp("cv", folds = 3))
rr$aggregate(m)

#german_credit_costs 
#               341
```

Why is it working with `predict_type` is set to `'prob'`? Is this a bug or does the measure internally convert probabilities into classes? I guess the threshold for predicting a class as positive or negative is internally set to 0.5? Can one change this threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msr("classif.costs")` uses the confusion matrix for calculation: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/blob/master/R/MeasureClassifCosts.R

When `predict_type` is set to `prob` the confusion matrix is generated with a threshold of 0.5. To change it after you have a resample object:

```
pred = rr$predictions()
lapply(pred, function(x) x$set_threshold(0.1)) #arbitrary threshold

rr$aggregate(m)
```

to change it back:

```
lapply(pred, function(x) x$set_threshold(0.5))
rr$aggregate(m)
```

The "beauty" of R6 active bindings.